# Using Adodb recordset in visual basic 6 to VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vb6, ado.net

This codes below are working with visual basic 6.0 and I wanted this code to be used in vb.net and I think there are errors when I typed it on vb.net(Visual Studio 2013)

the name of my MS access database is "mySavings.accdb"

the table name is "Balance" with a field named "Balance"

I already added the reference:
Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.0 Library
Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Recordset 6.0 Library
Thank you in advance and here's my code in VB6

```
Public con As New ADODB.Connection
Public rs As New ADODB.Recordset    
    Dim Amount as String
Private Sub Form_Load()
    con.Open ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = C:\Users\MyPc\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\mySavings.accdb")

    rs.Open ("Select * from Savings"), con, 3, 2
    Amount = rs!Balance
    msgbox("You're current balance is " & Amount)
End Sub
```

Comment: WHY do you think it has errors? If it doesnt compile or throws errors what are they? if you have errors in the VB.NET code, why did you post the VB6 code (or is that a typo)?

Comment: the error here is the

Amount = rs!Balance

it says that "Overload Resolution because no accessible 'Fields' accepts this number of arguments"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been awhile since I've used ADODB but I think this should work

```
Amount = rs.Fields.Item("Balance").Value
```

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in BrentWorks.exe

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'ADODB.InternalField' to type 'System.String'.

Comment: What type is `Balance` in the db? Maybe those need to match?

Comment: What do you mean by type?
    Balance  is a Text data type. how can it be matched? what are the syntax? Thank you in advance

Comment: rs.fields.item returns an ADODB.Field object (not a string).  You should use:  rs.Fields.Item("Balance").Value

Answer (score 0):

It's that rs!Balance piece of code that's not right.
Another way to do this:

```
    Dim Amount As Decimal = rs.Fields("Balance").Value
```